# a STACK (or bunch) of food in British english. Make sense?

Tags: difference

People say "I eat a bunch of food" in North American English, it sounds natural. But what if I say...

> ..."I eat **a STACK of food**"

in British English? **Does it make sense?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stacks imply putting one item on top of another, such that you can't get the bottom item without removing the top item first.

Some foods are served stacked.  It is very natural to say

> I ate a stack of pancakes.

But not all food is stacked.  For example, one would be very confused to hear

> I ate a stack of soup.

I believe that the person who says "stack of food" is using slang, or a local term that wouldn't sound natural outside of their community.  The phrase isn't common English.

Now some food contains items that are stacked, like a hamburger.  But a hamburger is not a stack of food, because food is a general term, not limited to the items making a hamburger.  And "a stack of hamburgers" is only used when one whole hamburger is placed on top of other whole hamburgers.